# Qml: есть ли возможность преобразовывать типы?

Tags: qt, qt5, qml

В моём коде есть такая строка:

```
var someName = index as String;
```

Qml при запуске программы на этой строке выдаёт ошибку:

> Expected token `;'

В чём может быть дело? Поддерживает ли qml ключевое слово as?

Answer (score 0):

Qt QML позволяет писать [скрипты в коде QML на JavaScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html#javascript-environment-for-qml-applications). Так как [ключевого слова `as` в `JavaScript` нет](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp), то и выдается подобная ошибка.